# mySQL Replication Error. login incorrect

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-error-1064

I have been trying to setup MySQL replication for the first time. I read many articles and it appears very easy, but I guess I made a typo when setting up the slave. I am getting the following error in the error log.

> 2016-10-02T14:29:45.479004Z 1 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'abcd123@server3:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 2628, Error_code: 2003

I looked it up and "error 2003" said that the user cannot login to the master I guess.  Which is correct cause server3 is incorrect. That was my typo.  I have 3 servers

> Server1 Master mysql
>    Server2 Slave mysql
>    Server3 web server.

So server3 is incorrect. I tried to change the login using the command.

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='10.0.0.1',MASTER_USER='abcd123',MASTER_PASSWORD='PASSWORD',;
START SLAVE;
```

But I am still getting the error above.

Comment: Is that you have checked privileges of replication user

Comment: @khalid that user has dba rights. Full system rights. But the key is server3 isn't right.  I need the user to not be server 3

Comment: How can you say server 3 isn't right.

Comment: server 2 running fine?

Comment: Server3 doesn't have MySQL on it. It's a web server. I assume I made a typo when I first set it up. Server1 and server2 are MySQL servers and server 3 is web. Both MySQL servers are running great

Comment: Well they are running fine except for the replication

Comment: You have setup replication between server1 and server2...?

Comment: Did you checked `show slave status\G` on server 2

Comment: Well I thought I did but I must have set it up wrong. Since according to the log it is trying to contact the server and the account looks wrong by the log file it looks like it is using an account from server 3. Which is wrong. No MySQL on server 3. I tried changing it with the command above but it appears to be wrong  command.

Comment: `show slave status\G` check this on server 2 and let's see is there any error.

Comment: I did do a show slave status.  here is the output

Comment: |Connectingtomaster|server1|ROOT|3306|60
||4|server1-relay-bin.000001|
4||Connecting|Yes|
||||
||0||
0|0|154|None|
|0|No||
||||
0|No|1045|errorconnectingtomast
er'ROOT@server1:3306'-retry-time:60retries:2729|0|
||0||C:\
ProgramData\MySQL\MySQLServer5.7\Data\master.info|0|
NULL|Slavehasreadallrelaylog;waitingformoreupdates|86
400||16100211:40:33||
||||
0||||

Comment: you are working on windows

Comment: Yes Windows server 2012 r2

Comment: `step 1` check bind-address in master server configuration. `step 2` create a user and grant replication on it.

Comment: I need about 20 mins to get to that. I'll let you know asap

Comment: ok waiting...just add a comment.

Comment: Ok yes it appears that user has full rights. I even looked and verified the user is a dba with all check boxes checked in workbench.

Comment: I just looked in the my.ini file on the master and there is no bind-address entry. Should I add one?

Comment: No need to add. try to connect master remotly

Comment: I have done that. Works fine

Comment: You have tried to connect server1 from server2 remotely. I mean connect master from slave.

Comment: If you are able to connect to server1 from server2 then replication will do same.

Comment: When you have checked user privileges, did you check host either it is `localhost` or `%`

Comment: Yes I connected to the master from the slave

Comment: It was %. I had changed it a couple days ago from local host

Comment: Now is it `%` or `localhost`

Comment: Currently it is %

Comment: good `stop slave;` and apply change master and `start slave;`

Comment: I think that may have done it. Thank you so much. I am not getting errors in the log.  I will add data to the database and verify they made it

Comment: try once after 60 second

Comment: Yes I just did a sql and it appears to have replicated the data. Thanks so much. You have been a very big help

Comment: I will write answer if it helped then accept it.

Comment: I will accept thanks so much

Comment: Written my answer, to know more visit my blog http://mysqlglobal.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of replication is not connecting check basic thing

- First step will check user table and privileges related to user.
- The second will be bind-address in configuration.
- The third, you might forgot to flush privileges.
- Another is checking host if that user either it has `%` or
  `localhost`.
- If everything looks fine then `stop slave;`
- Apply change master properly
- And then `start slave;`

Check for any error `show slave status\G`;